# How to install different Swirl courses in R

Tags: r, swirl

I am able to successfully load the SwirlDev/swirl_courses.  However, I cannot figure out how to load a course from a different repository.
The repository I am trying to use is:
`https://github.com/DataScienceUWL/UW_Stat_Methods`

I've cloned it into local desktop GitHub, and have tried both:
`install_course(course_name = "UW_Stat_Methods")` - error is no internet connection

`install_from_swirl("UW_Stat_Methods")` - error is course not found (which makes sense)

I've tried setting the work directly to the local GitHub repo, but makes no difference.

I've googled this for over an hour, but nothing seems to help.

Any tips?

Comment: There is an install_course_github function,  have you used that?

Comment: I did now.  The way to do this is: install_course_github('DataScienceUWL','UW_Stat_Methods')  Thanks!!

Comment: I think you could probably delete this question or else you could answer it yourself (and accept your own answer).

Answer (score 0):

The answer is
install_course_github('DataScienceUWL','UW_Stat_Methods')

Thanks for the assist!